# Are there examples of finite-dimensional weak Hopf C*-algebras with non-involutive antipode?

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras, subfactors, planar-algebras

For finite-dimensional (non-weak) Hopf C*-algebras it is known that the antipode is always involutive, as claimed e.g. in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.5283.pdf. I couldn't find the same statement for weak Hopf C*-algebras, however. Are there counterexamples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002212369993522X) of Nikshych-Vainerman, a finite-dimensional weak Kac algebra is precisely a finite-dimensional [weak Hopf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_Hopf_algebra) ${\rm C}^{\star}$-algebra with an involutive antipode ($S^2 = id$), and they give (p306) an explicit example of finite-dimensional weak Hopf [${\rm C}^{\star}$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra) which is not a weak Kac algebra.

More generally, any finite index depth $2$ unital inclusion of [type ${\rm II}_1$ factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra#Type_II_factors) is characterized by a finite-dimensional weak Hopf ${\rm C}^{\star}$-algebra and in the weak Kac case, the index is an integer. So every non-integer finite index depth $2$ [subfactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subfactor) provides an example of finite-dimensional weak Hopf ${\rm C}^{\star}$-algebra  with a non-involutive antipode. For any depth $n$ subfactor $(N \subset M)$ of finite index $|M:N|$, if $$N \subset M \subset M_1 \subset M_2 \subset M_3 \subset \cdots $$ is the [Jones tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subfactor#Jones_tower), then $(N \subset M_{n-2})$ is a depth $2$ subfactor of index $|M:N|^{n-1}$. The depth $n$ Temperley-Lieb-Jones subfactor has index $4cos^2(\frac{\pi}{n+1})$, and $[4cos^2(\frac{\pi}{n+1})]^{n-1}$ is not an integer for $n \neq 2,4$, so the corresponding weak Hopf ${\rm C}^{\star}$-algebra  has a non-involutive antipode (it should also be the case for $n=4$, but not for $n=2$). The example of Nikshych-Vainerman above is $n=3$.

---

[This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123604000795) of Das proves by [planar algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_algebra) techniques that for any finite index depth $2$ subfactor  $(N \subset M)$, the relative commutants $N' \cap M_1$ and $M' \cap M_2$ has a structure of finite-dimensional weak Hopf ${\rm C}^{\star}$-algebra. What does the diagram on p84 say about the antipode $S$?

Comment: The diagram p84 says that the antipode $S$ is a contragredient up to conjugation (i.e. $S(a) = w^{-1}  \overline{a}  w$), and is involutive up to conjugation (because $S^2(a) = w^{-2} a w^2$).

Comment: Editing a dozen old questions in the space of a few minutes drives newer questions off the front page. Please don't do that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Sorry about that. By the way, what are you doing at the front page?

Comment: I don't understand your question. When one goes to https://mathoverflow.net one lands on the front page.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: sure, but do you go through all the questions on the front page (everyday)? If so, why? My personal use of MathOverflow is through "filter subscriptions" and newsletter emails.

Comment: Each to his own.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to the question in the OPs answer.

I just took a brief look into

> Rehren - *Weak C* Hopf symmetry* in Quantum Groups Symposium at
>   "Group21", eds. H.-D. Doebner et al., Goslar 1996 Proceedings, Heron
>   Press, Sofia (1997), pp. 62-69. https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9611007

which does the type III case.

The point is that $S^{-1}(q)=S^\ast(q^\ast)$, which is what the diagram on p84 in the mentioned article says.